# How can I get the coordinates of a graphics primitive from a Graphics expression?

Tags: graphics, expression-manipulation

For example I have

```
square = Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0} ,{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]]
```

What functions can I apply to `sqaure` to extract the coordinates of the polygon? It is necessary to do this kind of extraction when I have a graphics object as an argument of a function, and want to use coordinates taken from primitives within it to do some calculation.

Comment: `Cases[square, Polygon[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]]` or `square[[1, 1]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cases[square, Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity][[1]]
```

or

```
square[[1, 1]]
```

both give

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
Extract[square,Position[square,{_,_}]]
```

Maybe this will help. In a 2-D graphics object, generally this code can extract all the coordinates.

Maybe there'll have some problem e.g. like some options with the same form.....

I'm currently typing with my tiny phone without my computer, so if there's anything wrong with my code (not likely~), just inform me......I'll modify it after I get home.

Hope this can help you:)

Comment: this cannot preserve the stucture of the graphics, so if you want to know only points' coordinates in a graphics regardless of their usage (vertex of a square or line?) use this can help you. :)